# Consumer group name header for spring-cloud-stream kafka DLT message

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream

I'm looking for solution to add consumer group name as a header to DLT message. I was thinking about DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer but I can't find a way to make it work with spring-cloud-stream instead of spring-kafka.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a customized `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` with a custom `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer` by adding a `ListenerContainerCustomizer` `@Bean`.

However, if you do this, you should disable retry in the binder (set `maxAttempts=1`) and disable DLT in the binder too.

That way the retries and DLT are controlled by the container instead.

Please open a new feature request to the binder, I think adding that header is something that would be generally useful.